# Control Web Push notification display on screen

Tags: push-notification, service-worker, web-push

I am using webPushlib/webpush to send push notification from my node server.

Everything is working fine but when i trigger push notification it only shows for a few seconds.
I want to display until user action(click or close).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [requireInteraction option](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#require-interaction-preference-flag) of the [sendNotification method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification).